# Data filtration

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have the data of below type:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Election Yr.':[2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2005,2005,2005,2005,2005,2005],
                   'Party':['A','A','B','B','C','C','A','A','B','B','C','C',],
                   'Votes':[50,30,40,50,30,40,50,30,40,50,30,40],
                   'Odd':['aa','bb','cc','dd','ee','gg','ff', 'hh', 'jj', 'kk', 'll', 'yy']})
```

I want to groupby **Election Yr.** and sum the values in **Votes**, while keeping the values for **Party** that correspond to max value of **Votes** for each unique **Election Yr.** and first value for **Odd**.

I came up with a partial solution like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['Election Yr.'], as_index=False).agg({'Votes':'sum', 'Party':'idxmax', 'Odd':'first'}))
```

But the *Party:'idxmax'* seems to be incorrect since the values are strings

Answer (score 1):

You can create two dataframes:

1. With sum of Votes and first value of Odd, per year
2. With the party that matches the maximum value of the years (can be multiple)

```
df_sum_odd = df.groupby(['Election Yr.'], as_index=False).agg({'Votes':'sum', 'Odd':'first'})
df_party = df[df.groupby('Election Yr.').Votes.transform('max') == df.Votes][['Election Yr.', 'Party']]
df_sum_odd.merge(df_party, on = 'Election Yr.', how='right')
```

After merging those two you will receive the following result:

```
    Election Yr.    Votes   Odd Party
0   2000            240     aa  A
1   2000            240     aa  B
2   2005            240     ff  A
3   2005            240     ff  B
```

Note that there are two lines per election year, since there are two different parties that correspond with the max Votes value per year (50).